# Plugins slider não carregam

Tags: wordpress, slider

Já instalei vários plugins para o slider da home e nenhum deles carregam. Ou carregam e as imagens configuradas ficam uma abaixo da outra. O que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: formula melhor a pergunta.

Comment: Está parecendo que algum componente do plugin não foi devidamente carregado ou dando conflito com seu Wordpress. Dá uma olhada no console e veja se aparece algum erro.